# how to read multiple images from one folder in python using for loop?

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I have 5 images in folder. I want to access all these one by one and apply individual operation to all these images. 
i try

```
import cv2
import numpy
import glob
import pylab as plt
folders = glob.glob('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Asplab/Cifar/image31.png')
imagenames__list = []
for folder in folders:
   for f in glob.glob(folder+'/*.jpg'):
       imagenames_list.append(f)

read_images = []        

for image in imagenames_list:
   read_images.append(cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE))
```

NameError: name 'imagenames_list' is not defined

Comment: It's just because you defined a list with two `_` and at the end you would iterate on a list with one `_`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change "imagenames__list" to "imagenames_list"

```
import cv2
import numpy
import glob
import pylab as plt
folders = glob.glob('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Asplab/Cifar/image31.png')
imagenames_list = []
for folder in folders:
   for f in glob.glob(folder+'/*.jpg'):
       imagenames_list.append(f)

read_images = []        

for image in imagenames_list:
   read_images.append(cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo at line `6`

```
import cv2
import numpy
import glob
import pylab as plt
folders = glob.glob('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Asplab/Cifar/image31.png')
imagenames_list = []
for folder in folders:
   for f in glob.glob(folder+'/*.jpg'):
       imagenames_list.append(f)

read_images = []        

for image in imagenames_list:
   read_images.append(cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

Comment: error:   read_images.append(cv2.imread(image31, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
                                                                ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: its 32x32 image